# Request for migration

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The following question seems most appropriate to be directly answered in german.stackexchange.com:

> [In written German, how can I tell whether ⟨s⟩ is pronounced /s/, /ʃ/ or /z/? [on hold]](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19599/in-written-german-how-can-i-tell-whether-s-is-pronounced-s-%ca%83-or-z)

Can it be migrated (and reopened) there?

I think it has been flagged at least a couple times, but I haven't heard anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any flags, but prash has taken care of it, so I'm marking this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Thanks for the update.